# Вопрос относительно сравнительных оборотов с «как»

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Вопрос относительно сравнительных оборотов с «как». Правило мне известно, но, к сожалению, не всегда могу применить.
Не могу определиться: к приравниванию, к качеству, к уподоблению или вовсе к сказуемому относятся мои обороты. Сразу говорю, что не д/з, как вы можете подумать. Немного появился затор в процессе написания романов. (Или уже, наоборот, «много»!)
Если несложно, поясните свою позицию с примерами, мне важно для дальнейшей работы, как вы понимаете. В общем, помогите, пожалуйста. Вот, собственно, они самые(предложения):

**Яна оставила подругу наедине с оборудованием, как врач, прекрасно понимая, что дело далеко не в гриппе.**
(Думается мне, что речь идет о качестве, следовательно, запятая не нужна. Но как-то без нее мне нехорошо!)

**Поэтому мой тебе совет как человеку, испытывающему дискомфорт: для собственного спокойствия перестань насильно будить свою совесть, а вместо этого делай то, что нравится. Но как другу я советую не впускать Марка глубоко в свою жизнь и продолжать бороться со своей сутью.**
(Вроде бы тоже на лицо качество, но опять же не уверена.)

**Пока справляюсь и иллюзия на месте, надо бы придумать, как поступить дальше, мы ведь недолго будем так стоять - они как упертое стадо, а я как новые ворота.**
(Вот тут я совсем потерялась. Приравнивание? Тогда правильно. А может, уподобление или вовсе к общему сказуемому «стоять» относятся? Тогда просчиталась.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Значение причины (поняла, потому что была врачом): Яна оставила подругу наедине с оборудованием, **как врач**, прекрасно понимая, что дело далеко не в гриппе.

2) Значение "в качестве (сейчас я рассматриваю тебя как человека, испытывающего дискомфорт). Поэтому мой тебе совет **как человеку**, испытывающему дискомфорт: для собственного спокойствия перестань насильно будить свою совесть, а вместо этого делай то, что нравится.

3) Значение "в качестве (сейчас я рассматриваю тебя **как друга**).  Но как другу я советую не впускать Марка глубоко в свою жизнь и продолжать бороться со своей сутью.

4) Пока справляюсь и иллюзия на месте, надо бы придумать, как поступить дальше, мы ведь недолго будем так стоять - они **как упертое стадо**, а я **как новые ворота.**

Неполные предложения с пропуском сказуемого, но без тире: они (будут стоять) как упертое стадо. Оборот в роли  обстоятельства.